# Is it a subgroup?!

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group,  $A$ an its subset and put $A^{-1}=\{ a^{-1}:a\in A\}$.

Is it true that if $A$ is symmetric (i.e., $A=A^{-1}$),  $G=AB$ and $|AB|=|A||B|$, for some $B\subseteq G$, then $A$ is a subgroup of $G$?

**Note:** The converse is true, i.e., if $A$ is a subgroup then there exists such a subset $B$.

Comment: I'm prepared to be wrong about this, but isn't a sub-semigroup of a **finite** group always a subgroup? The sub-semigroup is closed under powers (with positive exponent), and you get both the identity and the inverses among them.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Do you consider the conditions (sub-semigroup is closed under multiplication, not only powers)  ?

Comment: Isn't closure under powers a consequence of closure under multiplication?

Comment: Yes. Note that we have some additional conditions for the semigroup.

Comment: My point was that given a sub-semigroup $A$ of $G$ both the existence of a matching subset $B$ and the requirement $A=A^{-1}$  are redundant. A sub-semigroup of a finite group is automatically a subgroup.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Let $G=S_3$, $A=\{(12),(13),(23)\}=A^{-1}$ and $B=\{1_G,(12)\}$. Then $A1_G$ (resp. $A(12)$) consists of all the odd (resp. even) permutations of $G$. The size conditions are also  met, but $A$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: Here the key was that a coset of the subgroup $A_3$ happens to be closed under inversion.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple counter-example is: $G = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, $A = \{\overline{0}_6, \overline{1}_6, \overline{5}_6\}$, $B = \{\overline{0}_6, \overline{3}_6\}$.